# Is this the proper way to make a C function, no return statement, with open,write,close file?

Tags: c, function, file-io

I am making a C function for the first time, this is what i want it to do. Take in three inputs, (int,int,ast) and if it is one case, open the file named "quad.q" and then writes, and then closes.

```
    void quadGen(int lineNumber, int sizeOfGlobal, struct ast* a)
{
    if(lineNumber == 1 && sizeOfGlobal = 0 && a == null)
    {
        FILE *f = fopen("quad.q", "w+");
        if(f == NULL)
        {
            printf("error opening file!\n");
        }
        const char *text ="$ 1 0\n # 2\n h";
        fprintf(f,text);
        fclose(f);

    }
}
```

Comment: It is fine since you have declared this function of type void.

Comment: @ChuanzhenWu So this properly opens, writes, and closes a file, and has no return type. I just want to write to the file in a certain case.

Comment: Yes it is. You definitely can write void function like this. Sometimes if you need to break the function you can use a single "return", but as a void function you don't need to return anything.

Comment: Try compiling. What are `null` and `a`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot comment on the condition itself, but most likely `sizeOfGlobal = 0` should be `sizeOfGlobal == 0`.

[`fopen(..., "w+")`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) is for reading and writing, the file is created or truncated. In your case `w` is sufficient, unless you want to append. In this case, use `a` or `a+`.

When opening the file fails, you shouldn't continue, but skip `fprintf` or return from the function, e.g.

```
if(f == NULL) {
    printf("error opening file!\n");
} else {
    const char *text ="$ 1 0\n # 2\n h";
    fprintf(f,text);
    fclose(f);
}
```